# Make sure placeholders on PowerPoint slides made from layouts have set names

Tags: vba, layout, powerpoint

I've been struggling with this for a bit, so I thought I'd see if anyone here has a solution.

I'm trying to write a PowerPoint VBA add-in to automate certain things in reports that my team produces. Right now we have a number of slide layouts that we use for different things, an example of which is pictured here:
[image: Layout Example]

(Shape names on the right are in french because the person who creates the templates is in France).

For my add-in to work, I need to be able to target specific placeholders on the slide, but when a slide is created from this layout the placeholders have random names (seen here):
[image: Slide Example]

What I've been doing up to this point is using the generated placeholder names, because they are the same on each slide generated from that layout (i.e. the "Issue Title" is always "Text Placeholder 3"). However, this can change when something is changed in the layout, which then breaks everything.

What I'd like to do is be able to name something on the layout (i.e. "IssueTitleBox"), and have the resultant text placeholder on the slide named the same thing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This may have something to do with the fact that shapes in PPT have a name AND a name property, usually but not always the same. You might be able to modify the name by editing the underlying XML, but I've never had a go at this, so can't say for sure. One thing I'd be cautious of:  it appears from the screenshots that several of the shapes on the slides have the same name. This isn't supposed to happen (but does sometimes) and can lead to odd behavior; inability to rename the shapes later, or PPT returning the wrong shape when you ask for one by name.